# Get All Available Facebook Pages With Koala Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

Is there a way to get all the available Facebook pages via the koala gem?  I need to cache this data.  I'm not trying to associate a user with them.  Just grab all the possible pages in a cron task so I can cache them.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get "all Pages", you can only use the Search API to search for specific ones. Check out the docs for information on how to do that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search